# Why the updation of mobile applications require installation of whole apps again?

Tags: mobile-application

I am new to mobile application development(basically android). I was just wondering that, whenever,  we try to update an application, every time, the whole app has to get installed, which is frustrating. Just imagine, reinstalling whole apps for "minor bug fixes". Couldn't we just update that particular feature of the app. That would save a lot of time and money, especially for people in remote areas, where the internet speed is very low.

I searched for a proper answer but couldn't find any.

Thanks, in advance!!

Comment: I think its just a matter of convenience to the platform providers (simpler than maintaining various "deltas"). App images are relatively small compared to, say, videos and hence saving on bandwidth is perhaps not a major issue.